# Add syntax "where" in the model, but not selected (datatables ajax codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

[[Datatables joining tables search and order stuck with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385680/datatables-joining-tables-search-and-order-stuck-with-codeigniter][1])

the case is the same at this link, see the correct answer, but why can't it be given "where"?

```
private function _get_datatables_query($term=''){ //term is value of $_REQUEST['search']['value']
    $column = array('k.id_kota','k.nm_kota', 'p.nm_propinsi');
    $this->db->select('k.id_kota, k.nm_kota, p.nm_propinsi');
    $this->db->from('kota as k');
    $this->db->where('k.id_kota',2); //this problem
    $this->db->join('propinsi as p', 'p.id_propinsi = k.id_propinsi','left');
    $this->db->like('k.id_kota', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('k.nm_kota', $term);
    $this->db->or_like('p.nm_propinsi', $term);
    if(isset($_REQUEST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
       $this->db->order_by($column[$_REQUEST['order']['0']['column']], $_REQUEST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
       $order = $this->order;
       $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}
```

I will showing all data basic id.kota = 2 but can't. Please help. Thanks

Comment: I think your `where` clause should be after all your joins.

Comment: @H45H its the same Sir, can't selected by id.kota

Comment: Also, where should be just before your ORDER by. and after the JOIN and it's conditions. Speaking of conditions, I do not see where you set the JOIN condition, In other words, how the two tables are related. There should be something that compares a column in one table to a column in the other table.

Comment: @AndreaSha The order of the `where` clause is not causing a problem here,  and the syntax is valid too. Could you show the codes on how do you call this `_get_datatables_query()` function?

Comment: Show me the result of `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: It does not matter what order the Query Builder functions are called, the actual query string will not be constructed until `$this->db->get()` is called and Query Builder will make sure all the clauses are put together in the correct order.

Comment: @AndreaSha, are you getting an error? Data not filtered? It is not clear what is wrong.

Comment: Where did you call `$this->db->get()`, put `echo $this->db->last_query()` after that. If you haven't added  `$this->db->get()` then add this. Without this query will not get executed.